# How to change default template for Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the template that  Word 2007 is based on?](https://superuser.com/questions/53172/how-to-change-the-template-that-word-2007-is-based-on)

How do I change the default template for Word 2007?

Now from Document Properties is says based on Normal.dotm.

And how do I change Normal.dotm, Normal.dotx I can change but not Normal.dotm.

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/53172/how-to-change-the-template-that-word-2007-is-based-on, I suggest closing this one since it has fewer answers.

Comment: Fewer answers is good, as long as they answer the question correctly and adequately. Less to read one day that way.

Answer (score 1):

- [image] -> Open -> Click "Templates".
- Make sure the filter for "file type" is set to **All Word Templates**
- Select **Normal.dotm** and click open
- Make changes that you want to be defaults
- Save