# How to change the template that Word 2007 is based on?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How do I change what template is based on by default?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Orb in the top left, then Open.

Click Templates, then "Normal".

[image]

Any changes you make here should now be the default document that is always opened.

Comment: pretty screenshots! I wouldn't have known where to look for this myself - Ofice 2k7 moved so many things around, it's very hard to switch-to, compared to all the previous editions, I think

Comment: @warren, thanks! just wish I could write with a mouse better! A Wacom (or cheap copy) has been on my want list for a while - but I doubt my handwriting would be much neater!

Answer (score 0):

All document settings are stored in Normal.dot. Your best bet at changing the template is to just edit that file. You can find more information regarding normal.dot [here](http://www.officearticles.com/word/about_normal_dot_in_microsoft_word.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have your very own, customized templates for your documents - In any word document, if you go to Tools - templates/Add-Ins you can point to a template file of your choice. 
Hope this helps.

EDIT: Sorry I didnt notice that your Word version is 2007. MIne's 2003 - so I cant say for sure if the options still apply in 2007. You can perhaps try and see if it has been retained though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing template with which you wish to replace the standard Normal.dotm template, save your template as a macro-enabled template (.dotm) and, with Word closed, delete the existing Normal.dotm template and rename your new template to Normal.dotm.

On a standard Windows installation of Office 2007, the templates in question are stored by default at C:\Documents and Settings\ *[YOUR USER NAME]* \application Data\microsoft\templates